# Limit Cancellation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity, rational-functions

So I was working on a HW problem, namely proving the power rule for derivatives of real functions with positive integer exponents. The proof is routine but at some point, you end up doing cancelling to "factor a zero" out of a rational expression, i.e when taking the limit of something like this:
$$
\lim_{x \to 5}\frac{(x-5)(x+5)}{x-5} = \lim_{x \to 5} (x+5)  = 10
$$
So this made me a bit curious and I now wonder if this is true in the general case, i.e if: $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : A \to \mathbb{R}$, and
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0,\ \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = p
$$
then
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)} = p
$$
I attempted an epsilon-delta solution but am not really sure where to go from there. It is pretty easy to do if you assume continuity of $f$ at $a$, but I am not sure how to work with the other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can cancel is because $(x-5)\neq 0$ when $x$ is close to *but not equal to* $5$.

The statement you propose is *not* true in general - take $f(x)=0$. Then the quotient $\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}$ is not even well-defined. Similar problems occur if $f(x)$ takes on the value $0$ infinitely many times as $x$ approaches $a$ (what I mean is there is a sequence $(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=a$ and $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n$).

Rather, the condition that must hold in order to cancel the $f(x)$ terms is that there exists a punctured neighborhood of $a$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$ on that neighborhood. That is, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $f(x) \neq 0$. In fact, you do not even need to assume $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists, because when taking limits it only matters what values the function takes *close* to $a$, but not *at* $a$. So as long as $f(x) \neq 0$ close to $a$, you can cancel the numerator and denominator.